# How to host Wordpress site on Android device

Tags: web-server

I am trying to host a Wordpress site on my old Android phone, but so far I have been unsuccessfull...

I tried with [KSWEB](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.kslabs.ksweb) and [Ulti Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.ultiserver), extracted the Wordpress.zip in the sdcard, and when I try to connect to the server I am getting error with the database...

```
Error establishing a database connection
```

Does it also has to run some other SQL server on the phone for everything to work?

I really don't know what am I doing, and there aren't any good explanations on the internet, so please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wordpress requires a database to run.

After installing [KSWeb](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.kslabs.ksweb), you will need to create a database for Wordpress.  To do this:

1. Open [KSWeb](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.kslabs.ksweb).
2. Go to **Tools** → select **phpMyAdmin** (it will install).
3. Open Chrome browser.
4. Go to `localhost:8000` (to connect to phpMyAdmin).
5. Select the **Databases** tab.
6. In the box below the label **Create Database** enter `wordpress`, select **create**. Your wordpress database should now be created.

Now wordpress needs to be setup.

1. Move your wordpress folder (unzipped) to `/mnt/sdcard/htdocs/`.
2. Open a browser and go to `localhost:8080/wordpress`. It will ask you to setup your database connection.
3. Enter `root` for the **username** and clear out the **password** field (you can leave everything on the default settings).
4. Select **Submit**.

It should now connect WP to your database.

Thought about using a [Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/)?  I've setup several Wordpress Sites on the Pi (with MySQL) and you can set it up with your network for local website hosting.

References:
[Wordpress - Do I need a database](https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_Installation#Do_I_need_to_create_a_database.3F)

Comment: so can I host some other website, made with different platform? I want it to be on my phone

Comment: or how can I run a database server along with the other server?

Comment: See the modified answer on setting up everything

Comment: I've gotten way further than before, it's all good now, but I can't seem to be able to access the Wordpress server from external IP, I have configured my router to forward the 8080 port, but now I can't connect to the KSWEB server (I was able to connect externally to a server made with Ulti Server, but this one is giving me problems...). Any help?

Comment: Can you access your WP server on the same network (the LAN) that your phone is on (e.g. 192.168.1.8:8080 on your broswer from a different device)?  Are you specifying the port when connecting from outside?  Are you connecting from a different public IP than your phone is on? There will be issues if connecting from the same network.  What is the error msg that you are getting?

Comment: Yes, I can connect to the Wordpress site from another phone connected to the same Wi-Fi. But if I try from my computer, using the external address of the KSWEB server, like this 78.83.***.***:8080 (with, or without /wordpress at the end) it simply doesnt load.

Comment: If your computer is on a different public IP than your phone, it sounds like a routing issue.  If your computer shares the same public IP address, you will not be able to connect.  Try using a proxy if that's the case [public proxy](https://hide.me/en/proxy)

Comment: no, its something to do with the KSWEB server, I even tried with my phone on celular data, and still can't access it... and I know its KSWEB because I can access a server created with Ulti Server, from my computer

Comment: I did it, all I had to do on the router was forward the ports like this: 8000 > 8000 instead ot 8000 > 80 and so on